# Validating inputs for a 2D- Character Array

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, boolean, tic-tac-toe

I have some code that I am working on, and I am stuck. How do I check a 2D character array for correct character(s) input? I am simulating a tic-tac-toe game, and only want 'x' and 'o' for my inputs, anything else should yield a   "`cout << "Sorry you can only enter 'x' and 'o'" << endl; exit(1);`"

This is what I've tried so far, but this does not work! Can someone just explain it to me? I am a beginnner in c++, so I only know the basics, but basciaclly I have to check all 9 array locations for the correct input `'x'` or `'o'`.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Declare 2D array
    const int SIZE = 3;
    char board[SIZE][SIZE];

    // Read x's and o's
    cout << "Enter x's and o's on board (L-R, T-B): ";
    for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
            cin >> board[r][c];

    // Print 2D array
    cout << "\n+---+---+---+\n";
    for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++) {
        cout << "| ";
        for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++) 
            cout << board[r][c] << " | ";
        cout << "\n+---+---+---+\n";
    }

    // Check board contains only x's and o's
    bool valid = true;
    if (board[SIZE][SIZE] != 'x' || board[SIZE][SIZE] != 'o')
        valid = false;
    if (!valid) {
        cout << "Sorry, you can only enter x's and o's\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    // Check first diagonal to see who wins
    char winner = ' ';
    if ((board[0][0] == board[1][1]) && (board[1][1] == board[2][2]))
        winner = board[0][0];

    // Check second diagonal to see who wins
    if ((board[2][0] == board[1][1]) && (board[1][1] == board[0][2]))
        winner = board[0][0];

    // Check rows to see who wins
    for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
        if ((board[r][0] == board[r][1]) && (board[r][1] == board[r][2]))
            winner = board[r][0];

    // Check columns to see who wins
    for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
        if ((board[0][c] == board[1][c]) && (board[1][c] == board[2][c]))
            winner = board[c][0];
    // Print winner
    if (winner != ' ')
        cout << "Congratulations " << winner << " is the winner\n";
    else
        cout << "Sorry, no one wins\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `board[SIZE][SIZE] != 'x' || board[SIZE][SIZE] != 'o'` is always true. If the character is equal to `x` then it's obviously not equal to `o`, and vice versa. You likely meant `&&` in place of `||`

Comment: Besides, `board[SIZE][SIZE]` accesses an index out of bounds. Valid indexes are `0` through `SIZE-1`. You already know how to access every element of the board - you do it right above, in the loop that prints it out.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! My brain is fried from midterms right now, but wow that was a simple fix! It works now!

Comment: Watch your indentation. Aim for consistency. It will help you (and others) to read your code.

Comment: @AdrianPena *My brain is fried from midterms right now* -- You could have created a function, call it `bool isValidEntry(char c) { return c == 'x' || c == 'o'; }`.  Then in your `main` function, simply call `if (!isValidEntry(board[r][c]))` to determine if the character is invalid.